# Weblogic Error The error is weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND

Tags: java, weblogic

I am using web logic server 10.3.6 and trying to deploy and run the existing project.

i got error like

```
problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'module@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element application@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:234)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:221)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:146)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:306)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:409)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
    at weblogic.application.ApplicationDescriptor.getApplicationDescriptor(ApplicationDescriptor.java:311)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:174)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:88)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationForAppDeployment(MBeanConverter.java:66)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.setupNew81MBean(MBeanConverter.java:314)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:110)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:39)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:187)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:21)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:233)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:165)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:122)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:173)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:89)
    at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

<13 Nov, 2013 5:22:53 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149605> <Failed to create App/Comp mbeans for AppDeploymentMBean _auto_generated_ear_. Error - weblogic.management.DeploymentException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'module@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element application@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>.
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'module@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element application@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeploymentFactory.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(EarDeploymentFactory.java:189)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.findOrCreateComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.createComponentMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:110)
    at weblogic.application.internal.MBeanFactoryImpl.initializeMBeans(MBeanFactoryImpl.java:76)
    at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.MBeanConverter.createApplicationMBean(MBeanConverter.java:88)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4c: Expected element 'module@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee' before the end of the content in element application@http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:234)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.evaluateResults(MarshallerFactory.java:221)
    at weblogic.descriptor.internal.MarshallerFactory$1.createDescriptor(MarshallerFactory.java:146)
    at weblogic.descriptor.BasicDescriptorManager.createDescriptor(BasicDescriptorManager.java:306)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.getDescriptorBeanFromReader(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:788)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Post your config file but it looks like you are missing an element. Did you modify your config file manually?

Comment: yes i have added this `<sec:user-lockout-manager>
        <sec:lockout-enabled>true</sec:lockout-enabled>
        <sec:lockout-threshold>5</sec:lockout-threshold>
        <sec:lockout-duration>30</sec:lockout-duration>
        <sec:lockout-reset-duration>5</sec:lockout-reset-duration>
        <sec:lockout-cache-size>5</sec:lockout-cache-size>
        <sec:lockout-gc-threshold>400</sec:lockout-gc-threshold>
      </sec:user-lockout-manager>`

Comment: looking at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/schemaref/security/http.www.bea.com.ns.weblogic.90.security/types/realmtype.user-lockout-manager.html you may be missing the "name" element.

Comment: +1 to Rob - post your Config file please.

Comment: hi I am also facing same issue while deploying one ear file ,can you please which config file need to correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
<sec:user-lockout-manager> 
    <sec:lockout-enabled>true</sec:lockout-enabled> 
    <sec:lockout-threshold>5</sec:lockout-threshold> 
    <sec:lockout-duration>30</sec:lockout-duration> 
    <sec:lockout-reset-duration>5</sec:lockout-reset-duration> 
    <sec:lockout-cache-size>5</sec:lockout-cache-size> 
    <sec:lockout-gc-threshold>400</sec:lockout-gc-threshold>
    <sec:name>some_name</sec:name>
</sec:user-lockout-manager>
```

according to the link 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/schemaref/security/http.www.bea.com.ns.weblogic.90.security/types/realmtype.user-lockout-manager.html

there is an name component thought it is supposed to be optional.

Comment: if i add this the server not started `<java-compiler>javac</java-compiler>
<client-cert-proxy-enabled>true</client-cert-proxy-enabled>`

Comment: I have added the name element. but still same issu